# Oracle query - calculate date and time difference - Overlapping

Tags: oracle

oralce query how to calculating hours with overlapping

```
ID    startdate                enddate                      hours
a124     10/10/2019 07:30:00    10/10/2019 11:30:00            4
a124     10/10/2019 07:00:00    10/10/2019 15:10:00            8.17
bc24     10/10/2019 07:30:00    10/10/2019 11:30:00            4
bc24     10/10/2019 10:30:00    10/10/2019 15:30:00            5
er67     10/10/2019 09:30:00    10/10/2019 11:30:00            2
er67     10/10/2019 15:30:00    10/10/2019 16:30:00            1
```

Desired Output :

```
    ID    startdate                enddate                      hours
   a124   10/10/2019 07:00:00     10/10/2019 15:10:00           8.17
   bc24   10/10/2019 07:30:00     10/10/2019 15:30:00            8
   er67   10/10/2019 09:30:00     10/10/2019 11:30:00            2
   er67   10/10/2019 15:30:00     10/10/2019 16:30:00            1
```

[image: Output based on below query]

Output based on below query

Comment: Why is the desired output for a124 equal to 8.67 hours? The first interval is entirely within the second, so the answer should be 8.17, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes , should be 8.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the whole answer.

You need to use `NOT EXISTS` to remove the row for which start and end dates are between others (not overlap but total inclusion) and `aggregate` function as following

Table creation:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE T AS
  2  (SELECT 'a124' ID,     TO_DATE('10/10/2019 07:30:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') STARTDATE,    TO_DATE('10/10/2019 11:30:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ENDDATE,            4 AS HOURS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'a124',     TO_DATE('10/10/2019 07:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),    TO_DATE('10/10/2019 15:10:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),            8.17 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'bc24',     TO_DATE('10/10/2019 07:30:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),    TO_DATE('10/10/2019 11:30:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),            4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'bc24',     TO_DATE('10/10/2019 11:30:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),    TO_DATE('10/10/2019 15:30:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),            6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'er67',     TO_DATE('10/10/2019 09:30:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),    TO_DATE('10/10/2019 11:30:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),            2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 'er67',     TO_DATE('10/10/2019 15:30:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),    TO_DATE('10/10/2019 16:30:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),            1 FROM DUAL)
  8  ;

Table created.
```

Query to fetch the desired data

```
SQL> SELECT
  2      ID, MIN(STARTDATE), MAX(ENDDTAE),
  3      ROUND(SUM(CASE
  4          WHEN PREV_ENDDATE BETWEEN STARTDATE AND ENDDATE THEN ENDDATE - PREV_ENDDATE
  5          ELSE ENDDATE - STARTDATE
  6      END) * 24, 2) AS HOURS
  7  FROM
  8      (
  9          SELECT
 10              ID,
 11              STARTDATE,
 12              ENDDATE,
 13              LAG(ENDDATE) OVER(
 14                  PARTITION BY ID
 15                  ORDER BY
 16                      STARTDATE, ENDDATE
 17              ) AS PREV_ENDDATE
 18          FROM
 19              T TOUT
 20          WHERE
 21              NOT EXISTS (
 22                  SELECT
 23                      1
 24                  FROM
 25                      T TIN
 26                  WHERE
 27                      TIN.ID = TOUT.ID
 28                      AND TOUT.STARTDATE BETWEEN TIN.STARTDATE AND TIN.ENDDATE
 29                      AND TOUT.ENDDATE BETWEEN TIN.STARTDATE AND TIN.ENDDATE
 30                      AND TOUT.ROWID <> TIN.ROWID
 31              )
 32      )
 33  GROUP BY
 34      ID;

ID        HOURS
---- ----------
a124       8.17
bc24          8
er67          3

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This won't work if an ID has two non-overlapping intervals, will it?

Comment: Yes, it will not but I went through sample data

Comment: Tejash  , when I ran the above query I am getting 0.506 hrs  instead of 8.17 hrs (a124  id)

Comment: I have mentioned it in answer itself

Comment: Thanks @Tejash , Hours difference worked fine. Also , I want to display startdate and enddate . I have edit my desired outptut

Comment: ID    startdate                enddate                      hours
a124     10/10/2019 07:30:00    10/10/2019 11:30:00          8.17
a124     10/10/2019 07:00:00    10/10/2019 15:10:00            8.17
bc24     10/10/2019 07:30:00    10/10/2019 11:30:00            10
bc24     10/10/2019 10:30:00    10/10/2019 17:30:00            10
er67     10/10/2019 09:30:00    10/10/2019 11:30:00            3
er67     10/10/2019 15:30:00    10/10/2019 16:30:00            3

Comment: I did use max and min . ER67 id gave me on record
"er67 10/10/2019 09:30:00 10/10/2019 16:30:00 3"

Comment: @Tejash  Suppose to show  two records for er67 id
 " er67   10/10/2019 09:30:00     10/10/2019 11:30:00            2
   er67   10/10/2019 15:30:00     10/10/2019 16:30:00            1"

Comment: can anyone please help me?

Comment: I think you should ask another question to avoid the mess and mark this answer as resolved.

Comment: Sure will do Thanks @Tejash